# Grouping panda by time interval + aggregate function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Let's say I have a panda like that:

```
2010-01-01 04:10:00:025     69
2010-01-01 04:10:01:669     1
2010-01-01 04:10:03:027     3
2010-01-01 04:10:04:003     8
2010-01-01 04:10:05:987     10
2010-01-01 04:10:06:330     99
2010-01-01 04:10:08:369     55
2010-01-01 04:10:09:987     5000
2010-01-01 04:10:11:148     13
```

And I need convert it in a format as following:

```
2010-01-01 04:10:00:000     69      69
2010-01-01 04:10:05:000     5000    10
2010-01-01 04:10:10:000     13      13
```

The first column corresponds to each 5 seconds interval starting at 2010-01-01 04:10:00:000.

The second column is the max of all the grouped rows.

The third column is the first of all the grouped rows.

How can I get that?

Comment: Do you mean 5 seconds? Since the data you show is all withing roughly 11 seconds.

Comment: Yes, 5 seconds sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean `5 seconds`, we can use `pd.Grouper` with `agg` and `min, first`:

```
# use this line if your first column is not datetime type yet.
# df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='col1', freq='5s'))['col2'].agg(['max', 'first']).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
                 col1   max  first
0 2010-01-01 04:10:00    69     69
1 2010-01-01 04:10:05  5000     10
2 2010-01-01 04:10:10    13     13
```

---

Note: since you didn't provide column names, I called them `col1, col2`

Comment: Yes, I meant seconds. It looks good but the last column is not the minimun. It is the first of the grouped rows. I edited my question to better understanding

Comment: I see, I edited my answer, we are using `first` as aggregate function now instead of `min`. This should be correct @Alfonso_MA

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your first column is datetime named: `date_time` and your 2nd column in '`value`'. In order to reach your objective you can use the "[resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)" such that

```
   df.set_index('date_time').resample("5s").agg(['max','min'])
```

*note I used 5 seconds because your data didn't show 5 minute

result

```
                             value
                             max     min
      date_time     
      2010-01-01 04:10:00    69      1
      2010-01-01 04:10:05    5000    10
      2010-01-01 04:10:10    13      13
```

Comment: Yes, I meant seconds. The last column is not the minimun. It is the first of the grouped rows. I edited my question to better understanding

Comment: @Alfonso_MA you're right! it's not min it's first. You can simply change it in the code. thanks for pointing out.